# Identification of VOX/ADPCM-like format needed

Tags: conversion

I'm dealing with an odd format here, and it seems similar to VOX ADPCM, 8000Hz, but it when played back as such, produces the most horrendous sound. It's definitely similar to VOX ADPCM or some variant thereof, but I've been trying to identify it.

Here is the raw file:
http://www.sudomemo.net/wav/BGM.bin

I renamed BGM.bin to BGM.vox and ran
 `sox BGM.vox -t wav BGM.wav`: 
http://www.sudomemo.net/wav/BGM.vox.wav

This is how it should sound:
dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20459451/dsifull.mp3

Any ideas? This has baffled us so far. Here's some of the BGM.bin file:

```
[root@node1 sound]# xxd BGM.bin
0000000: 0000 0000 ff77 ff77 f860 800f 68ca 2298  .....w.w.`..h.".
0000010: 3898 b078 9929 112d 1991 bb27 8e02 a001  8..x.).-...'....
0000020: a22a 4a99 5a90 9924 b93a 971f 930b 038a  .*J.Z..$.:......
0000030: 4989 9168 8a49 89a9 62ea 1389 8092 2a1a  I..h.I..b.....*.
```

Comment: I have a nagging feeling in the back of my head that there may be a better place to post this; instead of downvoting if there is, please let me know and I would be more than happy to relocate the question. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is on-topic here, but I also can't think of anyplace better.  It is of interest to a sound designer though, so I'm not going to do anything directly unless the community voices some disapproval of the question.  This is probably the most likely place someone would recognize it.

Comment: Yes, I sure hope that I'll have some luck. This is quite the perplexing puzzle!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the question is about sound design per se, but it's a funny puzzle nonetheless.

Importing it to Audacity using Import > Raw Data and choosing VOX ADPCM Mono 8000Hz Little Endian does produce the sound like in your mp3, or at least similarly distorted and compressed. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to find out how to convert the raw audio so it sounds as good as the mp3; which was recorded from a headphone jack.

Comment: Tl;Dr: raw file ---?→ usable audio

Comment: So why don't you try the method I posted, using the free program Audacity? Once it succeeded in importing the audio format with the right settings, you can export it in any format you like.

Comment: Because I already did. Audacity produces the same mangled, horrific sound that using sox does; when importing as 8000Hz raw audio, VOX ADPCM. I need to be able to produce usable audio; which should sound like that mp3 file.